# Get post meta returns "" when meta is set in code and not by using post edit page

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

In a admin screen, I have a input box.  The user selects a date which in input into the input box.  When the user clicks a button the date is put into a meta field called "_yl_lease_security_refund_date" through an ajax call to a method that uses update_post_meta.  I can verify that the update_post_meta works because I then do a get_post_meta and send the value back in the ajax response.  However, if I leave the screen and then come back to it, the get_post_meta call returns "" as the value of the input box unless the meta value is changed through the edit post page.  How can I get my meta value updates to persist?  Here is my for the method that the ajax calls:

```
function yeager_srr_post_date_refunded() {

$result = 'Not Updated';
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
    $is_meta_updated = update_post_meta( $_POST['lease_id'], '_yl_lease_security_refund_date', $_POST['refund_date'] );
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $_POST['lease_id'], '_yl_lease_security_refund_date', true);

    if( $is_meta_updated !== false) {
            $result = 'Saved';
    }
    echo $result . '-' . $_POST['lease_id'] . '-' . $_POST['refund_date'] . '-meta_value=' . $meta_value; //. $value;       die();
}
else {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $_POST['lease_id'] ) );
    exit();
}
}
```

Here is the code I use the put the value in the input box if the value already exits.

```
$security_refund_meta_value = get_post_meta( $row[6], '_yl_lease_security_refund_date', true);
echo '<td>' .
'<input type="text" name="date_refunded_' . $row[6] .
'" id="date_refunded_' . $row[6] .
'" value="' . $security_refund_meta_value .
'" class="datepicker srr-refund-input" data-leaseid="' . $row[6] .
'" data-refunddate="' . ( empty( $security_refund_meta_value ) ? '' : $security_refund_meta_value ) . '">' . '</td>';
```

Comment: You need a little jQuery or  js script to update the input from the Ajax response. Search about wp_ajax_{$action}

Comment: The ajax code is good.  It seems the get_post_meta is not getting the same meta key/value as the updat_post_meta is adding and updating.  But I am not sure how that is possible.